# downgrade to babel 6.2.3

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using react js and I installed babel 7 in my pc.
when I open react js app with command

> npx create-react-app project_name

and then i make

> yarn eject

I get package.json (part of it)

```
"dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.1.0",
"@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
"babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
"babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
"babel-jest": "23.6.0",
"babel-loader": "8.0.4",
"babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.2.3",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^6.1.0",
"bfj": "6.1.1",
```

but I get some issues with babel 7 so i want to downgrade to last babel ^6.23.0".
I installed it globally and when I run on cmd

```
babel --version
```

I get

```
6.23.0 (babel-core 6.26.3)
```

but when I try to create new project again with
create-react-app 
I get the same babel core 7.0 but I don't want it.
I want this babel (like my other projects)

```
 "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-core": "6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
"babel-jest": "20.0.3",
"babel-loader": "7.1.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
"babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
"base64-img": "^1.0.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of create-react-app, version 2, uses babel 7. You can opt to use the older version of create-react-app like this:

```
npx create-react-app@1 project_name
```

Comment: I did and it open my react version 16.6.3 and when I do yarn eject it install babel 7